# Request for a Question to be Reopened

Tags: discussion, status-completed

My [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/499312/overwrite-existing-ubuntu-install-with-12-10-server-installer) was closed as vague. I have edited it and think it's now readable. I really need some help on this, and the question fits the scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I have re-opened it, however it's unfortunately still off-topic for server fault. Good news though - it's totally not off-topic for our ubuntu-specific site, so I will move it there for you.